# Mongo production database has suddenly disappeared

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services

I have an app in production. I logged on this morning to the AWS server and saw all Mongo databases are gone! When I go into the mongo shell and type:

```
show dbs
```

I just see:

```
WRITE_ME  0.078GB
```

What does this mean?

When I check in the database I see:

```
db.WRITE_ME.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("592fe13817b8b234e8bc0f61"), "email" : "request@firemail.cc", "btc_wallet" : "1GCgiza9buq4WdEtrsRjbvZMcbnnvCsZwH", "note" : "Your DB is in safety and backed up (check logs). To restore send 0.1 BTC and email with your server ip or domain name. Each 24 hours we erase all data." }
```

**EDIT**

I have a backup but it's a few days old.

My app only has about 300 users. Its a Node app running on AWS connectiong to a local MongoDB instance. How could they have hacked this? Would they have gone through SSH?

Comment: You've been hacked?

Comment: Wow, is that it? How could that be possible? Im on AWS

Comment: I can't tell, but there is a chance that your credentials have been compromised.. However, you must have a backup.. Do you?

Comment: Ouch, you've been hacked. Did you have any credentials on your database? The default for mongo db credentials used to be to have none.... Unfortunately you'll be very lucky to get this back even if you pay the bitcoins, it's more likely whoever has done this has just deleted your database.

Comment: I have a backup but its a few days old @Oscar

Comment: @Matt no credentials. I have an AWS server, a node app, and a local mongodb. Does this mean they SSH's onto my server?? How could they delete the DB?

Comment: See [here](https://continuum.cisco.com/2017/01/09/hacker-gold-rush-ransoms-mongodb-databases-en-masse/), it's been happening a lot unfortunately. Not sure about your AWS setup but the db was clearly available for them to do this and not simply "local" to your server.

Comment: See [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/q/218005/153161) at sister site [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com).  Do not repair this system.  Preserve the evidence and work from the assumption that this system cannot be secured.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks. I have since repaired it. I hadn't any users or permissions set up for mongo and it was also publically facing which it didnt need to be. From the mongo logs, it looks like they just dropped the database. I think im ok to keep using what i have

Comment: Assuming they accessed it directly, externally, and nothing else was compromised, you may be right.  Kudos for actually reading the logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have been hacked and hacker want 0.1 BTC from you to restore your databases. In most cases you will never see your data even if you pay for this.